# Using IndexedDB to save images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, indexeddb

```
<img src="picture_1.png" id="imgHolder"/>
```

Would like to save image with indexedDB in database named Images on button click.

```
<button id="write" onclick="saveToDB()">Save To DB</button>
```

Another button will read image from Images database to display in `<div id="resultContent"/>`.

```
<button id="read" onclick="readFromDB()">Read from DB</button>
```

Comment: There is a useful code sandbox: https://codepen.io/MSEdgeDev/pen/YqqOLd

Answer (score 26):

General idea is:

1. Create a database with a specified name. Use `indexedDB.open()` for that.
2. Create an `objectStore`.
3. Read a file(image in your case) as blob. Use `XMLHttpRequest` for that.
4. Create a db transaction.
5. Save file blob in the DB.
6. Read file blob from database.
7. Create URL using `URL.createObjectURL()` function
8. Insert url in `src` attribute in an `image` tag.

See more: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible. Inside of @Yauhen's answer is a [link to a Mozilla article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/) that can explain one possible implementation. I'll offer some additional context and an alternative solution using `canvas`.

`indexedDB` is an indexed key/value store that can store any type of JavaScript object that can be so-called "[cloned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm)." A handy heuristic is that essentially anything you can pass to a Web Worker you can pass to IDB.

To store images, you turn them into strings. Strings can be cloned, so they can  `saveToDB()` and `readFromDB()` without issue.

One way to turn an image into a string representation is [`createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL), which you do on a `URL` object. My preferred method is `toDataURL()` [which are found on `canvas`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15685877/317937) Either way you're looking at intermediate steps to

1. load your image to either a blob or a canvas then
2. extract that data into a storable string.

Comment: why do you prefer `canvas`'s `toDataUrl()`?