# How to reference a local file from Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, web, local-storage, flutter-web

The idea is the following: I need users to be able to pick images from their local filesystems, and somehow make the images available the next time the user uses the app. Browser local storage only gives you so much space so the idea is to only save their address and retrieve the image when needed. If anyone has a better solution that would be greatly appreciated, as I understand that moving/deleting the image would result in it not being retrievable.

**Note** I want to accomplish this **without** needing a backend.

Is this even possible? I know `dart:io` is not supported on web.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more specific to web platform itself than Flutter.

Recommended solution on Web is to store it in IndexedDB: [Using IndexedDB to save images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740186/using-indexeddb-to-save-images)

IndexedDB is supported natively by `dart:html`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-indexed_db/dart-indexed_db-library.html