# how to snapshot a part of HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am drawing a full-window graph with the HTML5 canvas feature, and what I want to do is to define a small square of region inside this canvas, and snapshot that the part of region into certain format, like png, jpg or a base64 text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a new canvas in background with the width and height of the image you want to take:

```
 var bgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 bgCanvas.width = 200;
 bgCanvas.height = 150;
```

Then copy a part of the original canvas to the background canvas using [context.drawImage](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#drawing-images-to-the-canvas). This example copies the 200x150 section starting at 400:500.

```
var bgContext = bgCanvas.getContext('2d');
bgContext.drawImage(mainCanvas, // source
                    400, 500,   // source coordinates
                    200, 150,   // source dimension
                    0, 0,       // target coordinates
                    200, 150);  // target dimensions
```

Now you just have to get the base64-encoded version of the bgCanvas as already explained in  question "[Getting binary (base64) data from HTML5 Canvas (readAsBinaryString)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685698/getting-binary-base64-data-from-html5-canvas-readasbinarystring)".

Comment: Hi,Philipp, I just encounter a problem that the main canvas (its id is mainCanvas) is my original HTML5 generated graph, but when I translate the main canvas into the a base64 based text with the methods var abcUrl = mainCanvas.toDataURL(); console.log(abcUrl);  The output of translated image is actually a black picture. Why it is black

Comment: @user824624 There are multiple reasons why this could happen. You should ask this as a new question with a minimal sourcecode example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I posted the problem in another post with my code - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535181/can-not-snapshot-the-html5-canvas-using-todataurl