# Can not snapshot the HTML5 canvas using toDataURL()

Tags: html, canvas

I am building a three.js animation, and try to snapshot the animation throught HTML5 canvas feature using  [Getting binary (base64) data from HTML5 Canvas (readAsBinaryString)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685698/getting-binary-base64-data-from-html5-canvas-readasbinarystring).

I tried but with no success, the snapshot I got is white blank, without the canvas animation. I don't know it is because of my broswer support, I am using the Opera

Here is my entire code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="Mainapp">
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="Main">
                <button class="btn btn-danger"  ng-click="cropImage()">
                        CropImage
                </button>

    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">
      // revolutions per second
      var angularSpeed = 0.2; 
      var lastTime = 0;

      // this function is executed on each animation frame
      function animate(){
        // update
        var time = (new Date()).getTime();
        var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
        var angleChange = angularSpeed * timeDiff * 2 * Math.PI / 1000;
        cube.rotation.y += angleChange;
        lastTime = time;

        // render
        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        // request new frame
        requestAnimationFrame(function(){
            animate();
        });
      }

      // renderer
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      renderer.domElement.id = 'world';      
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      // camera
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
      camera.position.z = 500;

      // scene
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();

      // cube
      var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
      cube.overdraw = true;
      scene.add(cube);

      // start animation
      animate();




var angularT3 = angular.module('Mainapp', []);

angularT3.run(['$rootScope', '$location','$http', '$window', function ($rootScope, $location, $http, $window) {
    //$http.defaults.headers.post['x-csrf-token'] = $cookies['XSRF_TOKEN'];
       var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
       canv.id = 'snapshot';
       canv.width = window.innerWidth;
       canv.height = window.innerHeight;       
       document.body.appendChild(canv);

}]);

angularT3.controller('Main', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.cropImage = function (){
        console.log('crop image');

        var bgCanvas = document.getElementById('snapshot');
        var mainCanvas = document.getElementById('world');

        var bgContext = bgCanvas.getContext('2d');
        bgContext.drawImage(mainCanvas, // source
                            400, 500,   // source coordinates
                            200, 150,   // source dimension
                            0, 0,       // target coordinates
                            200, 150);  // target dimensions

        var jpegUrl = bgCanvas.toDataURL();
        console.log(jpegUrl);
        console.log(jpegUrl.length);

        var abcUrl = mainCanvas.toDataURL();
        //.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); 
        console.log(abcUrl);
        window.open(abcUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=600, height=200");
        window.open(jpegUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=600, height=200");

    }

});


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get the *tainted canvas* error?

Comment: I remember having to call `.freezeCamera` on the three.js scene when doing this.

Comment: To Scimonster, I got no errors in the canvas, it shows the picture, but just a blank picture. And to pdoherty926, I didn't find .freezeCamera API in three.js so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution, in order to make three.js work, it is neccessary to keep the preserveDrawingBuffer as true

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            preserveDrawingBuffer: true 
});
```