# toDataURL: throw an security error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to get the 64 base encode of the canvas. Below code throw an security exception: `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="345" height="345"></canvas>

var 
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = null,
    img    = new Image(),
    dataUrl = null;

var init = function() {
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    };
    /*img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";*/
    img.src = "./img/s1.jpg";
    console.log(dataUrl);   
};

if (Modernizr.canvas) {
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    init();
}
```

I also tried to add `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";` but then i get this exception `Image from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: `The toDataURL method will fail if the browser thinks you've drawn to the canvas any data that was loaded from a different origin, so this approach will only work if your image files are loaded from the same server as the HTML page whose script is performing this operation.`  from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685698/getting-binary-base64-data-from-html5-canvas-readasbinarystring

Comment: Ok. Now run it to `localhost` not getting any exception but the `dataUrl `  value to null.

Comment: and what about the `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";`? Did you re-added it to the code?