# Sending <canvas> image to PHP using JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I take some photos using the webcam. `HTML` looks like this:

```
<div class="camera">
<video id="video">Video stream not available.</video>
</div>
```

The taken photo is displayed using a `<canvas>`:

```
<div class="output">    
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Below, I have a `<form>` with a save button:

```
<form method="post">
<button name="savephoto">Save photo</button>
</form>
```

This is how I check in `PHP` if save photo botton is pressed: `if (isset($_POST['savephoto']))`
Now, how could I get the photo (from `canvas`) in `PHP` only using `JavaScript`?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685698/getting-binary-base64-data-from-html5-canvas-readasbinarystring) topic. Think that could help you!

Comment: may [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server) help.

Answer (score 0):

You should lookup canvas.toDataUrl().

Here is an article showing it in use: https://davidwalsh.name/convert-canvas-image

Answer (score 0):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Then add it to your form with a field and post your form with JS and in php side you can get this string and add it in a file.

```
      var form = document.getElementById("formID");
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "canvasImg");
      hiddenField.setAttribute("value", img);
      form.appendChild(hiddenField);
form.post();
```

In your php file you can get your image string with $_POST['canvasImg']
but in your html you have to set the php file in the submit attribute.

Comment: I get the part where I have the canvas photo in JS. But I don't get the part where I start to use it in PHP.

Comment: if you want to make the form submit automatically you have to do it with JS. So you use form.post() but to send data of your field you have to specify a php file which contains code for image. In this file you will have your image as a string with $_POST['canvasImg'] (something like data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhyAAiALM...DfD0QAADs=") Then you have to deal with it. Personnaly I write the image in a file and deal with the file but it depends of what you want to do.

Comment: I have both the `HTML` and `PHP` in the same file, is that a problem?

Comment: no it's the same thing just look how to detect when your form is submitting to handle you picture treatment. (I don't know how, genreally I use external file ;) )