# How to get access to canvas in the TOAST UI Component Image Editor?

Tags: javascript

I use [TOAST UI Component Image Editor](http://ui.toast.com/tui-image-editor) on a webpage. I'd like to to save the image to Base64 string. There are no properties in [imageEditor object](http://nhnent.github.io/tui.image-editor/latest/ImageEditor.html) to allow me to access the edited image in canvas. I searched Google and Stackoverflow, no results.

Comment: try to take a look [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685698/getting-binary-base64-data-from-html5-canvas-readasbinarystring) In any case I assume there should be  a download method

Comment: @gaetanoM, Thank you for your response. I take a look at download method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the file **tui-image-editor.js** for download function as suggested by gaetanoM.

The solution is to call for base64 string of the edited image. The base64 string starts after the **data:image/png;base64,** prefix.

```
imageEditor.toDataURL();
```

Where *imageEditor* is a global JavaScript variable declared during image load.

Comment: Here's the actual API reference http://nhn.github.io/tui.image-editor/latest/ImageEditor#toDataURL

Comment: it also opens a new window/tab showing image. how to prevent that ?? i don't want a new window

Answer (score 1):

It is using fabric.js library. You can access the canvas object directly by :

ImageEditor._graphics.getCanvas();

it will give you a fabric object, assign this to some variable and you can use fabric.js functions with this.