# How can I POST canvas data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, http, fetch, fastapi

I built a simple project using javascript and FastAPI. I would like to POST canvas image data in javascript to the server(FastAPI).

But, I get the 422 Unprocessable Entity error

```
# FastAPI
@app.post("/post")
async def upload_files(input_data: UploadFile  = File(...)):
     return JSONResponse(status_code = 200, content={'result' : 'success'})
```

```
// javascript
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 112, 112);
fetch("http://{IP}/post", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      input_data: imageData,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
```

here is my code. I am new one in javascript. so I don't know how can post data to server.
How can I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UploadFile` expects a file being posted to the endpoint in the `multipart/form-data` format - i.e. as a regular POST with a bit of added metadata.

Since you're retrieving the image data and submitting it as JSON body, that won't match the expected format. You [also want to use `canvas.toDataURL()` to convert the content to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685698/getting-binary-base64-data-from-html5-canvas-readasbinarystring) before trying to submit it through your API to avoid any UTF-8 issues with JSON.

```
const pngData = canvas.toDataURL();

// then in your request:
body: JSON.stringify({
  input_data: pngData,
}),
```

To handle this request change your view function signature to receive an `input_data` parameter (and use a better endpoint name than `post`):

```
@app.post("/images")
async def upload_files(input_data: str = Body(...)):
     # check the expected format (content-type;<base64 content>)
     # .. and decode it with base64.b64decode()
     return {'content': input_data}
```

Answer (score 2):

MatsLindh's way is correct but you can try upload image by formdata so you haven't convert to base64 then convert back to image

```
const dataURItoBlob = function(dataURI : string) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString : string;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
}
const url = canvas.toDataURL()
const file = dataURItoBlob(url)

//add file to formdata

const form = new FormData()
form.append('file', item.file)
//post this form in body
```